# How to sequentially allocate a value across multiple elements in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I would like to allocate a value across various elements sequentially running from bottom to top of those elements, until the allocate value is depleted, as depicted in the examples below. In the examples, the value to allocate is applied first to the lowest lettered element, second to the second lowest lettered element, etc. Any recommendations for how to efficiently do this?

**Example 1:**

```
Allocate_value <- 75

Element     Element_begin_value  Allocate Element_end_value
Element_A                    50         0                50 
Element_B                    50         0                50
Element_C                    50        25                25
Element_D                    50        50                 0 

Total allocated                        75
```

**Example 2:**

```
Allocate_value <- 39

Element     Element_begin_value  Allocate Element_end_value
Element_A                     5         2                 3 
Element_B                     5         5                 0
Element_C                    15        15                 0
Element_D                    12        12                 0 
Element_E                     5         5                 0

Total allocated                        39
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can probably done a bit more concisely, but we could do this by looking at the cumulative total (from the bottom) of `Element_begin_value`, cap that at the allocated amount, and then extract the change in that vs. the next row.

```
library(dplyr)

allocate <- 75
df |>
  mutate(cumsum_rev = sum(Element_begin_value) - 
           cumsum(Element_begin_value) + Element_begin_value) |>
  mutate(alloc_total = pmin(cumsum_rev, allocate)) |>
  mutate(allocate = alloc_total - lead(alloc_total, 1, 0))
```

result

```
    Element Element_begin_value cumsum_rev alloc_total allocate
1 Element_A                  50        200          75        0
2 Element_B                  50        150          75        0
3 Element_C                  50        100          75       25
4 Element_D                  50         50          50       50
```

Answer (score 1):

In the below I wrap the Jon Spring solution in a function, whereby the allocation value is applied (distributed) among the elements bottom-up (Element_D first, then Element_C, etc.) as my OP requests and as Jon Spring solves for, by setting function parameter `bottom_up = TRUE`. Otherwise, the function works in the reverse direction whereby the allocation value is applied among the elements top-down (Element_A first, then Element_B, etc.) by running the function without specifying the `bottom_up` parameter:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  Element = c("Element_A","Element_B","Element_C","Element_D"),
  Element_begin_value = c(50,50,50,3)
)

allocate <- 75

allocSeq <- function(df, allocate, bottom_up = FALSE) {
  df_output <- df |>
    mutate(
      cumsum_flow = if (bottom_up) {
        sum(Element_begin_value) - cumsum(Element_begin_value) + Element_begin_value
      } else {
        cumsum(Element_begin_value)
      }
    ) |>
    mutate(alloc_total = pmin(cumsum_flow, allocate)) |>
    mutate(allocate = alloc_total - 
      if(bottom_up){
        lead(alloc_total, 1, 0)
       } else {
        lag(alloc_total, 1, 0)   
       }
    ) |>
    mutate(Element_end_value = Element_begin_value - allocate) |>
    select(Element, Element_begin_value, allocate, Element_end_value)
  
  return(df_output) 
}
```

Running `allocSeq(df,75,bottom_up = TRUE)` correctly results in:

```
    Element Element_begin_value allocate Element_end_value
1 Element_A                  50        0                50
2 Element_B                  50       22                28
3 Element_C                  50       50                 0
4 Element_D                   3        3                 0
```

Running `allocSeq(df,75)` or `allocSeq(df,75, bottom_up = FALSE)` correctly results in:

```
    Element Element_begin_value allocate Element_end_value
1 Element_A                  50       50                 0
2 Element_B                  50       25                25
3 Element_C                  50        0                50
4 Element_D                   3        0                 3
```